# How to update the content of a file in Google Drive?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to update the content of a Google Doc file with the content of another Google Doc file. The reason I don't use the `copy` method of the API is because that creates another file with another ID. My goal is to keep the current ID of the file. This is a code snippet which unfortunately does nothing:

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.Get getDraft = service.files().get(draftID);
File draft = driveManager.getFileBackoffExponential(getDraft);
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.Update updatePublished = service.files().update(publishedID, draft);
driveManager.updateFileBackoffExponential(updatePublished);
```

The two backoffExponential functions just launch the `execute` method on the object.

Googling around I found out that the `update` method offers another constructor:

```
public Update update(java.lang.String fileId, com.google.api.services.drive.model.File content, com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent mediaContent)
```

Thing is, I have no idea how to retrieve the mediaContent of a Google file such as a Google Doc.

The last resort could be a Google Apps Script but I'd rather avoid that since it's awfully slow and unreliable.

Thank you.

EDIT: I am using Drive API v3.

Comment: Will this help?

`java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(newFilename); FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(newMimeType, fileContent); File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();`

Comment: You're reading the content from a file on your file system. Unfortunately, that does not help :( I must read the content from a file on Google Drive.

Comment: That can be done with spreadsheets. Not aware if it could be done for docs. Also, are you using v2 or v3?

Comment: The Drive API are not aware of the file type as far as I know, it should work with Spreadsheets as well as Docs. Regardless you said it can be done, how exactly? Also, v3 here.

Comment: No, I wasn't referring to Drive API. Spreadsheet has another set of APIs that could be used. You can get various types of feeds from it.

Comment: Yeah I used Spreadsheet API in the past, however here I am dealing with pretty much every Google format such as Docs, Slides or Forms.

Comment: If that's the case, then I don't think Drive API offers any usable functionality that could help with this requirement. Here, the only option I see is to download the file, make changes and then update file in Google Drive.

Comment: I thought about that, however it's not possible to download the file in Google format :(

Comment: Put a bounty on this question. Maybe someone will have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Google Drive REST update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update).

> Updates a file's metadata and/or content with patch semantics.
>
> This method supports an /upload URI and accepts uploaded media with
>   the following characteristics:
>
> Maximum file size: 5120GB Accepted Media MIME types: /*

To download a Google File in the format that's usable, you need to specify the mime-type. Since you're using Spreadsheets, you can try application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet. [Link to Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#partial_download) for more info.